# How to correctly target by class name?

Tags: javascript, class, toggle, target

I am trying to practice some things on JS, I want to toggle a number of divs on click to change their color but I can't seem to target correctly the first one. It was fine when I did it by tag name but by class it doesnt seem to work. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

EDIT. This is what my code looks like after your corrections.

```
<body>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="one">

        </div>
        <div class="two">

        </div>
        <div class="three">

        </div>
        <div class="four">

        </div>

    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

let boxOne = document.getElementsByClassName("one")[0]

boxOne.onclick = function() {
    alert("Clicked!")
}
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` takes a class name as a parameter. Not a CSS selector. Remove the `.`

Comment: You're right, dont know why I posted it this way but I did that... nothing changes.

Comment: If you want only the first, I'd use `document.querySelector(".one")`. Frankly, I think it's convenient to use `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` for most or all DOM selection.

Comment: Thanks, I value others' opinions because there are so many that I only know it's best to avoid the getElementById one. This is just for practice purposes and because no matter what I am doing, my code with ClassName still does not work XD But I have corrected it like others have said.

Comment: So the JS part is coming from `script.js`? And you just copy-paste it here under the `body` tag for more illustration? If this is true, are you sure, `script.js` is loading correctly?

Comment: @SMAKSS yep, the script does work because when I try changing the bg color to the whole screen to red for example, it does that.

Comment: Well, it's pretty weird . Because it should work perfectly. How do you distinguish your `<div class="one">` and your `<div class="two">` etc.? Do you got any error in your browser console?

Comment: @SMAKSS I know! what do you mean? The index [0] does that, no?

Comment: I understood the issue!! Had a css file that was targeting was targeting the boxOne with "container:nth-child". Ha. Had no idea that could interfere. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @SMAKSS I would've voted all your replies but I didnt know how to do that because they're replies and not a whole post so I just voted the one that seemed more complete and helped me beyond the scope of my question.

Comment: That's nice thanks for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to add that its better to assign an id and use getElementById if the selector is only used by one element.

```js
let boxOne = document.getElementById("one");
let allBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName("square");

boxOne.onclick = function() {
  alert("Clicked via ID");
}
const arr = [1, 2, 3];
arr.forEach(i => {
  allBoxes[i].onclick = function() {
    alert("Clicked via Class");
  }
})
```

```css
.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  margin: 20px;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">

    <div class="square" id="one">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="square" id="two">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="square" id="three">
      3
    </div>
    <div class="square" id="four">
      4
    </div>

  </div>


</body>
```

Comment: Thanks! My final goal is to create a "full screen" of little divs that can be clicked on and randomly change color on click - as I said, I am practicing a number of things :) in this case I think it'd be best to use querySelectorAll in the end but this ClassName thing is just for practice... and because apparently it does not work yet XD

Answer (score 0):

document.

1. getElementsByClassName returns array of elements with that className (without dot)
2. querySelector is used for css selectors (eg. ".one", "div.one")
3. querySelectorAll like 2. but returns array

Comment: Without dot? "one" not ".one"

Comment: boxOne is already the first element so remove the second "[0]"

Comment: wtih "document.getElementsByClassName("one")[0]" and boxOne.onclick it still does not work

Comment: @GraceP check my other post, it does work. Click on run code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

With this line:`document.getElementsByClassName(".one")[0]`
you are already targeting the div, so change out this:
`boxOne[0].onclick =`
to this:
`boxOne.onclick =`

Comment: but I dont wanna target the div cause I know how to do that, I want to target them correctly with ClassName :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
let boxOne = document.getElementsByClassName("one")[0]

boxOne.onclick = function() {
    alert("Clicked!")
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 30px;
  background: blue
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="one">

        </div>
        <div class="two">

        </div>
        <div class="three">

        </div>
        <div class="four">

        </div>

    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```